# Dblink unknown parameters

Tags: postgresql, dblink

I installed dblink on my PostgreSQL database with `CREATE EXTENSION dblink` and everything I want works. However when I try to use dblink on other databases, I get the error:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function dblink(unknown, unknown) does not exist
>    Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

I tried to install dblink there again, but it says:

> ERROR: extension "dblink" already exists

Comment: Please add the following information: 1) In which schema did you install `dblink` 2) what is the exact query that fails, and what is the `search_path` in effect.

Comment: How exactly are you calling `dblink()` ?